# Why is pointer_traits not defined for "T* const"?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

As seen on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits and related sites (also the boost implementation by boost intrusive), `pointer_traits` is not specialized for `T*const`. Why is that?

Comment: I would say because it applies to the variable you store the pointer in, not the logical pointer entity itself. It doesn't really matter for the properties/traits of a pointer how you store it.

Comment: I think this would be particularly necessary for rebinding, `std::pointer_traits<T*>::rebind<void>` should preserve the constness of `T`, that is give `void*` or `void const*` depending on `T`.

Answer (score 8):

Although this does not qualify as a strong motivation *against* specifying that a specialization of `pointer_traits<>` for `T* const` should exist, I guess an explanation why it was not included could be that `pointer_traits<>` is mostly meant to be used in a context where template argument deduction (and in particular type deduction) occurs.

Since type deduction disregards top-level cv-qualifications, a specialization for `T* const` or `T* volatile` or `T* const volatile` was probably deemed unnecessary:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void foo(T)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int*>::value, "Error"); // Does not fire!
//                                ^^^^
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int* const p = &x;
    foo(p);
}
```

Of course this does not mean that having a specialization for `T* cv` would harm in this scenario, I just meant to provide a possible explanation of why those specializations are missing.

Similarly, no specialization of `iterator_traits<>` is provided for `T* cv`.

Comment: I have a function template of type `foo(T&)`, and it fires :(

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, that's a situation where top-level cv qualifiers are not ignored. Just to clarify, I only tried to give a possible explanation of why the specialization is not there; I'm not advocating that it *shouldn't* be there (in fact, implementations seem to provide it for `shared_ptr<>`).

Comment: In `foo(T&)` a qualifier on `T` isn't top-level, the `&` is the top-level, and any cv-qualifier is "one level down"

Comment: @JonathanWakely in `foo(T&)`, the `T` is `int *const` (has a toplevel const), which is what I wanted to point out. The const there is not dropped like it is for `foo(T)`. Note that in `foo(T&)`, `T` has no `&`. It is the parameter type only that has it.

Comment: I was responding to Andy's comment: "_Yes, that's a situation where top-level cv qualifiers are not ignored._" That is wrong, there _is no_ top-level cv-qual in `foo(int* const&)` so it's inaccurate to say it's not ignored.

Comment: @JonathanWakely ah I see. perhaps he means the argument toplevel qualifiers (the argument has a toplevel qualifier 'const').

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I didn't mean the top-level cv qualifier of the function parameter's type, I meant the top-level cv qualifier of the *argument*'s type. The argument has type `int* const`, but in this case the `const` is not ignored for deducing `T`, exactly because of what you say. Maybe I just didn't express myself correctly - or perhaps even my clarification is wrong, if so please explain why

Comment: The notion of "ignoring top-level cv-qualifiers" applies to function parameter types (8.3.5 [dcl.fct] p5) not arguments, so I don't know how to process what you were saying and will shut up now :-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I meant 14.8.2.1/2: "*If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of A’s type are ignored for type deduction.*". But that paragraph applies "If P is not a reference type", so not in this case.